# How to attach directives served on request by server to running angular application

Tags: angularjs, client-server, velocity, templating-engine

I have a number of angularJs directives generated using velocity template engine

Based on request i want to serve respective directive and attach it to angular.

Basically i dont want to bundle up all directives instead i want to use only the one which is required (serve that and use)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $compile method to bind scope of a controller to the HTML block in run time.
Try https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FH0A46GZB2UV

In the above example, a directive is added to DOM in run time on an event. Similarly in your case, you can add the tag of the directive which has to be loaded, based on the response of an ajax call.